# Logout functionality for facebook in android app

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am implementing following simple functionality.
I have a simple button, clicking on which I am able to login to Facebook. I am using Facebook SDK for the same. When I click , the src image of the button(imageview) also gets updated.
Up to this point everything works fine. But when i click on the same button for logging out 
I get a

```
 android.os.networkonmainthreadexception
```

exception. 
Can anyone please help me solve this issue?

EDIT: 
my code is as follows:

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.fb_button:

        try{
        if(fb.isSessionValid())
        {
            try {
                fb.logout(getBaseContext());
                update_fb_buttonimage();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //button close session
        }

        else
        {
            fb.authorize(LoginPage.this, new DialogListener(){

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, "on Facebook error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, "on error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values)
                {
                    update_fb_buttonimage();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onComplete works",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancel()
                {

                }
            });
            //login in to facebook
        }

        }catch(Exception e){

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

thankyou!

Comment: i know this, but can you provide a good explanation for why this error happens in simple words? So that a beginner like me can understand. I believe on the intelligence and helpfulness of the people using this site !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is simply that you need to make your web service calls (or what-have-you) on a separate thread. So, quite simply, you’ll need to look into how to do threading with Android. Unfortunately this can be a bit of a pain because you need to make your service calls on a separate thread, but you need to update the UI on the main thread. Normally this would require passing data between the threads, which involves handlers or other complexities. Luckily the Android platform provides the Async Task to handle this, which alleviates some of this complexity and may help you avoid some clutter in your code.

Comment: thankyou very much!! Can you provide a small tutorial or an example

Comment: hello sir, i have added my code in the EDITS.
I am able to login to Facebook, but i am not able to logout. It has been suggested to me to use AsyncTask for the purpose by you and also i have read about it. Can you help me in achieving this task?

Comment: I have a single button for logging in and logging out

Answer (score 1):

This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. Run your code in `AsyncTask`

Comment: an example will be appreciated !! or a small tutorial (not the developer site one)